# How to split source table records is SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Source and target tables structure with data is given below. Source table has transaction type column, base on this column target table rows will be defined. Suppose: source table data are 
[image]

On first row SalesTranId=1 and TranType=monthly, as this is  a monthly transaction target table will be filled with 30 rows with value 500/30=16.6, as like below

[image]

When Source TranType=Yearly, target table must have 365 rows base on source table row.
How to do that in SSIS package.

**Source Table:**

[image]

**Target table:**

[image]

**SSIS package:**

[image]

Comment: This kind of thing is more easily done in the database, with a calendar table. (which will also correctly give you 365 or 366 days a year etc.)

Comment: @ Nick.McDermaid, it's an ETL project need to run batch then source data will be processed/split and fill the destination table. will you please describe in detail, how we can achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you first do some research on a calendar table. You can turn one row into 30 by cross joining with 30 rows out of a calendar table. At this point I'm not going to go into detail. First load your data into a staging table and investigate a calendar table

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Tab and Nick on this but you are adamant about doing it in SSIS.

You have to make some assumptions in order to make my logic work:

Monthly translates to 30, quarterly to 90, and yearly to 365.

1. Import your source.
2. Add a script component and create a 2nd output that your destination looks like.
3. Add the following code:

> ```
> //Determine Divisor
> int DIV = 0;
>
> switch(Row.TranType.ToLower())
> {
>     case "monthly":
>        DIV=30;
>        break;
>     case "quarterly":
>        DIV=90;
>        break;
>     case "yearly":
>        DIV=365;
>        break;
> }
>
> for (int i = 1; i<=DIV;i++)
> {
>    destBuffer.AddRow();
>    destBuffer.SalesTranID = Row.SalesTransID;
>    destBuffer.TranType = Row.TranType;
>    destBuffer.TranAmt = Row.TranAmt/DIV;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this in the dataflow, you will need to use a Script component.

Personally I would send the data as-is to a staging table, and do the splitting in a stored procedure as you move it from the staging table to the final destination table.  It will perform faster.

Comment: Source table has flat information, as transaction has complex information need to join and process with others tables then need to split data and put in destination table.Will you please defined steps of your process.

Comment: Which process, and what part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Initially target table is blank, base on source table TRAN-TYPE column target table records are split. Suppose now target table has more than one million records, rest of the information need to fill from dim records so target table one million records need to update with new information.

Comment: Your original question doesn't mention any of this.  I think you need to add it to your question with some graphics or code to explain what you mean.  Your comment above is too hard to follow.

Comment: you read carefully my comments thanks for your valuable effort, what I do now?suggest me better approach for best performance.

Comment: I don't know what more to suggest because you haven't provided enough detail about your problem.  The answer I have posted answers your original question.   I don't understand what else you need.